# complex cron expression to run the quartz job?

Tags: java, spring, cron, quartz-scheduler

I am using spring quartz. I need to run the job `every 10mins` from `Mon 9:00AM To Fri 5:00PM`.

It means job should start at 9 AM on monday and it should continue to run every 10 mins till 5PM Friday.

Could you please help me how can i write a `cron expression` for above time period?

Thanks!

Comment: How often do you want the job to start during that period?

Comment: every 10 mins it has to start...

Comment: The canonical answer to how to use cron: http://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it

Answer (score 2):

If you want the job to run every 10 minutes between 09:00 and 17:00 then the cron expression should look like this:

```
0 0/10 9-17 ? * MON-FRI
```

There's some great documentation on the Quartz site:

http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger

Comment: Ur expression runs every 10 minutes from 9 to 17. But my requirement is it has to start from Monday 9AM to Friday 7PM

Comment: it stops at 5Pm daily..But for me once it start on Monday 9 AM then it should run continuously every 10mins till Friday 7PM

Comment: OK. Then you'll need three cron expressions. One covering Mondays covering 09:00-23:59, the second covering 24 hours Tue/Wed/Thur, and a third covering Friday covering 00:00 - 17:00.

Comment: is it not possible with a single cron expression? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think so. You're looking for different rules on different days (or groups of days) of the the week.

Answer (score 2):

I think, following expression will solve:

`0 0/10 9-17 ? * MON-FRI`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this : 0 0/10 9-17 MON-FRI * * ?